# How to make divs be spaced at equal distance from each other so they will fit the screen width?

Tags: html, css

I want divs to fit the screen but not expand. I want these three divs to be spaced so that the first one will touch the left edge of the screen, the middle on will be in the middle and the third one will touch the right edge of the screen. How can I do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/z57qwp8e/

Click on the button below 
            
            
                Game 1

```
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="linktopage">
        <br />
        Click on the button below
        <br />
        <button>
           Game 2
        </button>
    </div>


</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="linktopage">
        <br />
        Click on the button below
        <br />
        <button>
            Game 3
        </button>
    </div>


</div>
```

```css
        .container {
            text-align: center;

            display:inline-block;
        }
        .linktopage {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: floralwhite;
            color: darkblue;
            height: 25vmin;
            width: 50vmin;
            display: inline-block;
            border-style: outset;
            border-radius: 20px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 4vmin;


        }
        button {
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: dodgerblue;
            border-radius: 20px;
            color: darkblue;
            height: 10vmin;
            width: 30vmin;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting your `.container` class around each item, just have one container surround them all and use flexbox: `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;`. Fiddle below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.linktopage {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: floralwhite;
  color: darkblue;
  height: 25vmin;
  width: 50vmin;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: outset;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vmin;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: darkblue;
  height: 10vmin;
  width: 30vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="linktopage">
    <br /> Click on the button below
    <br />
    <button>Game 1</button>
  </div>

  <div class="linktopage">
    <br /> Click on the button below
    <br />
    <button>Game 2</button>
  </div>

  <div class="linktopage">
    <br /> Click on the button below
    <br />
    <button>Game 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use flexbox. the `html` could look like this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="linktopage">
            <br />
            Click on the button below 
            <br />
            <button>
                Game 1
            </button>
        </div>


        <div class="linktopage">
            <br />
            Click on the button below
            <br />
            <button>
               Game 2
            </button>
        </div>


        <div class="linktopage">
            <br />
            Click on the button below
            <br />
            <button>
                Game 3
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

and then the CSS could look something like this..

```
.container {

            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .linktopage {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: floralwhite;
            color: darkblue;
            height: 25vmin;
            width: 50vmin;
            display: inline-block;
            border-style: outset;
            border-radius: 20px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 4vmin;


        }
        button {
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: dodgerblue;
            border-radius: 20px;
            color: darkblue;
            height: 10vmin;
            width: 30vmin;
        }
```